# How bad is Spin-Up Time in HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have a newly brought laptop and it has WD Black 7200 RPM HDD. And yesterday I took a screenshot from `CystalDiskInfo` and I kept it and today I just opened CystalDiskInfo and compared the values with that old screenshot and I see the `spin-up time` value has changed.
1 day ago the spin-up time was

```
Attribute Name | Current | Worst | Threshold
spin-up time   |    186  |   181 |    21
```

But today it is

```
Attribute Name | Current | Worst | Threshold
spin-up time   |    184  |   181 |    21
```

Why is the `Current` value is decreasing? And even this is a new HDD brought a month ago.
So I would like to know how serious is this problem and is anything wrong with the values shows in the CrystalDiskInfo. Anybody can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does it work in normal use?  A fully setup Windows Operating system can be running smoothly in 7 to 8 minutes on a 7200-rpm drive and 4 minutes or so on a fast SSD drive. If operating this way, it is likely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMART
[S.M.A.R.T. Attribute: Spin-Up Time](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9103)
is defined as:

> Spin-Up Time S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates an average time (in
> milliseconds or seconds) of spindle spinup (from zero RPM (Revolutions
> Per Minute) to fully operational).
>
> This parameter is considered informational by the most hardware
> vendors. Although degradation of this parameter can be an indicator of
> drive aging and/or potential electromechanical problems, it does not
> directly indicate imminent drive failure.

Spin up time may depend on many parameters, such as the
ambient temperature of the drive. This is why this parameter shows
an average value, rather than an exact one.

You should only be worried if this value starts to degrade, indicating
an aging disk. As in your case the time 184 is less than the average 186,
everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and detailed explanation. And also thank you for putting your time to answer this question.